# Flurry missing some iOS downloads

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, flurry

Flurry has been reporting about 25% less installs than I have downloads in itunes connect for one of my apps, **since my last update on 22/07**.

My app is primarily targeting middle eastern users, with USA coming as the second best region in iTunes Connect.

In flurry however, the USA installs have become close to 0.

For example, for the period of 29/07 to 04/08 I see 122 downloads for USA & Canada in iTunesConnect, and only 3 in Flurry.

Did anyone notice anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

Flurry needs your app to actually be opened to count installation.
App store reports gives you actual downloads, but the user can forget it in a corner and never open it. Be patient and the gap should reduce over time.

Comment: That's such a bad answer!
I'm seing a 95% difference between installs and downloads for only one of my apps, for only one region, and only since my last update (everything was fine before).
I agree some people may sometimes download apps and forget about them even before they opened it. 
But in my case it is so specific, that you can't explain it with a generic reason that should be evenly distributed and probably not account for more than 1 or 2% of the missing installs.

Comment: Well you said 25% in your original post, so I tried to find a reason to that ;)

Comment: 25% is overall, but specifically in the US I mentioned 3 installs instead for 122 downloads (~97% margin)